# Al hacer petición con axios en react pone la url del cliente antes de la del server, y al no poner la url, pone la del cliente

Tags: reactjs, react-axios, context

Al hacer una petición con axios en react pone la url del cliente antes de la del server. De hecho, si no pongo url pone la del cliente. ¿Por qué pasa esto?

```
const authenticate = (data) => {console.log('hereeee', URL);//Sale la URL bien
        axios.post(`${URL}/auth`,data)// aqui pone las 2 urls (cliente + server)
            .then(r => {
                if(r.data.Security.AccessToken){
                    setToken(r.data.Security.AccessToken);
                    login();
                }
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL en mayúsculas es una palabra reservada de javascript, reemplazarla por url en minúsculas podría resolver tu problema.

Ejemplo:

```
const URL = "http://server.com/"
axios.post(${URL}/auth,data)
```

Por:

```
const url = "http://server.com/"
axios.post(${url}/auth,data)
```

Otra cosa que puede causar eso es que no estés agregando el http o https en la URL.

Comment: Puse la url en minúsculas y sigue igual

Comment: Estas agregando en la url https://?

Comment: Nop y eso mismo era!! Muchísimas gracias! Es que siempre trabaje con servidores externos pero como este era local simplemente puse localhost sin http

Comment: Buenísimo, modifiqué la respuesta, si es posible marcarla como correcta así no queda abierta para siempre y si alguien más lo busca puede saber que es una solución. Me alegra que hayas resuelto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias a ti!!!